# c# get new list of elements grouped between certain element in list

Tags: c#, linq

in c# how do you get a new list of elements grouped by falling in between a certain element. for example if my list was ['visit', 'houston', 'and', 'san', 'antonio', 'and', 'austin', 'and', 'corpus', 'christi']

and i wanted to extract the cities between "and" into a new list grouped between the "ands" so the two word names cities are in a group together

In python you can use itertools but how can you accomplish this in c#?

```
import itertools as itt
    List =['visit', 'houston', 'and', 'san', 'antonio', 'and', 'austin', 'and', 'corpus', 'christi']
    >>> [list(g) for k, g in itt.groupby(L, key=lambda word: word=='and') if not k]
```

results-

```
[['visit', 'houston'], ['san', 'antonio'], ['austin'], ['corpus', 'christi']]
```

Comment: why not just split by "and" ?

Answer (score 2):

Combine them into a single string (or leave them that way if that's how they started), then split it by `and` and split each substring again:

```
var words = new[] { "visit", "houston", "and", "san", "antonio", "and", "austin", "and", "corpus", "christi" };

var sentence = string.Join(' ', words);  // "visit houston and san .... christi"

var cities = sentence.Split("and", StringSplitOptions.None)
                     .Select(x => x.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                     .ToArray();
```

[image]

Note that if your input includes spaces in them (like `..., "and", "san antonio", ...`) then this may need some adjusting.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use System.Linq.GroupBy with a little modification to add key as number of "and"s preceding the given word.

Group method:

```
static string[][] GroupByWord(string[] input, string word)
    {
        var i = 0;
        return input.GroupBy(w =>
        {
            if (w == word)
            {
                i++;
                return -1;
            }
            return i;
        })
        .Where(kv => kv.Key != -1) // remove group with "and" strings
        .Select(s => s.ToArray()) // make arrays from groups ["visit", "houston"] for example
        .ToArray(); // make arrays of arrays
    }
```

Calling method:

```
        var input = new[] { "visit", "houston", "and", "san", "antonio", "and", "austin", "and", "corpus", "christi" };
        var result = GroupByWord(input, "and");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach using loops.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetList(IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    while(source.Any())
    {
        var returnValue = source.TakeWhile(x=>!x.Equals("and")).ToList();
        yield return returnValue;
        source = source.Skip(returnValue.Count()+1);
    }
}
```

You can now do,

```
var words = new[] { "visit", "houston", "and", "san", "antonio", "and", "austin", "and", "corpus", "christi" };
var result = GetList(words);
```

Output

[image]